# Return key/value pairs in jq

Tags: json, ansible, jq, key-value

I have the following json output (generated by ansible) and a seemingly easy task of pulling a few key/value pairs out with `jq`. However, I can't seem to get the output I want.

```
{
"custom_stats": {}, 
"plays": [
    {
        "play": {
            "id": "001dd8b7-1cca-07c6-2280-00000000043a", 
            "name": "Ansible Ad-Hoc"
        }, 
        "tasks": [
            {
                "hosts": {
                    "hostname01-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname02-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname03-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname04-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname05-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname06-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname07-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname01-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname02-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname03-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname04-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname05-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname01-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname02-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname03-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname04-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname05-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname06-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }, 
                    "hostname07-con": {
                        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                        "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                        "action": "debug", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "hw_system_serial": "<SERIALNUMBER>"
                    }
                }, 
                "task": {
                    "id": "001dd8b7-1cca-07c6-2280-00000000043c", 
                    "name": "debug"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"stats": {
    "hostname01-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname02-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname03-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname04-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname05-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname06-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname07-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname01-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname02-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname03-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname04-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname05-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname01-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname02-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname03-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname04-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname05-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname06-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }, 
    "hostname07-con": {
        "changed": 0, 
        "failures": 0, 
        "ok": 1, 
        "skipped": 0, 
        "unreachable": 0
    }
}
```

}

Basically I'd just like the key of the inner-most object along with its value for `hw_system_serial`, returned on the same line. Something like this:

```
hostname01-con: <SERIAL_NUMBER_1>
hostname02-con: <SERIAL_NUMBER_2>
etc
```

I feel like this should be trivial (I could have written a little ruby or python script in this time...), but try as I might I can't get it correct. I've tried all sorts of things, but I either end up iterating over the list of hosts for *every* serial number or returning two separate lists (one hosts and one serial numbers).

For example, this:

```
.plays[].tasks[].hosts | keys as $hosts | .[].hw_system_serial as $serial | $hosts | join(": ") + $serial
```

returns a list of every host name on a single line followed by one serial number.

I *think* it will work if I can convert `$serial` to an array, but my attempts to use `split()` have also failed (e.g. `$serial | split("\r")` returns a list of single-item arrays rather than an array of items).

What am I missing here? I feel like `jq` should have an easy time with this (again, any scripting language with a JSON parser...), but is it just not the right tool for the job?

Comment: your provided input is missing a closing brace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is feasible for `jq` tool:

```
jq -r '.plays[].tasks[].hosts | to_entries[] | "\(.key +": "+ .value.hw_system_serial)"' input.json
```

The output:

```
hostname01-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
hostname02-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
hostname03-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
hostname04-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
hostname05-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
hostname06-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
hostname07-con: <SERIALNUMBER>
```

Comment: or similar: `jq -r '.plays[].tasks[].hosts | to_entries[] | [ .key,  .value.hw_system_serial ] | join(": ")'`

Comment: Hmm, I had played with `to_entries` as well but I guess I didn't have the right syntax. Thanks for the help — I'll keep this in my back pocket for next time.